# XML в виде HTML таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Нужно вывести содержимое XML файла в виде HTML - таблицы. Я делала по примеру отсюда http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.a..._display_table. Но почему-то на странице ничего не выводится. В чем проблема?

Файл HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="json_fun.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="getXML"></div>
<p><input value="XML" onclick="getXmlFun()" type="button"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Файл stock.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<root>

<string>
    <id>1</id>
    <td_date>12.01.2015</td_date>
    <name>Внимание! Акция от ТМ «Лакалут»!</name>
    <text >
        При покупке зубной пасты ТМ «Лакалут вайт» или «Лакалут актив» Вы получаете скидку 30% на зубную щетку ТМ «Лакалут вайт» или «Лакалут актив». 
        </text>
</string>


<string>
    <id>2</id>
    <td_date>12.01.2015</td_date>
    <name>Уважаемые родители! Не упустите возможность принять участие в акции.</name>
    <text>
    При покупке джамбо упаковок Pampers Premium и Pampers Activ Вы гарантировано получаете подарок*! 
    Главный приз-фотосессия для Вас и Вашего малыша.</text>
</string>


<string>
    <id>3</id>
    <td_date>03.12.2014</td_date>
    <name>Вольтарен эмульгель со скидкой 15%!</name>
    <text>
    С 01.12.2014  при покупке Вольтарен эмульгель 50 г., Вы получаете скидку 15%. 
    Скидка по акции не суммируется со скидкой по дисконтной карте.</text>
</string>


<string>
    <id>4</id>
    <td_date>03.12.2014</td_date>
    <name>Скидка 50% при покупке двух единиц ТМ Бюбхен</name>
    <text>
    С 01.12.2014 по 31.12.2014 при покупке двух единиц продукции ТМ «Бюбхен» Вы получаете скидку 50% . 
    Скидка действует на позицию с более низкой ценой.</text>
</string>


<string>
    <id>5</id>
    <td_date>03.12.2014</td_date>
    <name>25% скидка от ТМ NUK!</name>
    <text>
    С 01.12.2014 по 31.12.2014  при покупке любой продукции ТМ «NUK» Вы получаете скидку -25%. 
    Скидка 25% не суммируется со скидкой дисконтной карты.</text>
</string>

</root>
```

Файл json_fun.js:

```
function getXmlFun(){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","stock.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

    var str =  '<table border="2" width="600"><th>id</th><th>date</th><th>name</th><th>text</th>';
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("string");

    for (i  =0; i<4; i++)
      { 

      str += "<tr><td>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" + 
      x[i].getElementsByTagName("td_date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
      x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
      x[i].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td></tr>";
      }
    str += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("getXML").innerHTML = str;
}
```

Comment: чего пишет в отладчике?

Comment: @teovankot ошибок никаких не выдает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле он вам пишет вот такую ошибку:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/stock.xml. Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.getXmlFun @
>   json_fun.js:9

Проблема заключается в том, что нельзя просто так обратиться через `XMLHttpRequest` к локальному файлу, другими словами нельзя обратиться по адресу начинающемуся с `file://` или `C:/`. Это нужно для безопасности, чтобы нельзя было просто взять и слить файлы с локальной машины помощью js.

Вы можете положить ваш файл на вэбсервер и обратиться к нему по протоколу `http://` вот так:

> http://какой-то-хостинг.рф/stock.xml

Comment: То есть локально нельзя подключить? Может существует еще какой-то способ решения проблемы? Мне нужно просто отобразить XML в HTML файле в виде таблицы

Comment: Можете попробовать xml определить в виде текстовой переменной. Но разве тяжко локальный вэбсервер поднять?

Comment: если честно, не пойму что подразумевается под "поднятием локального вэбсервера"

Comment: спасибо огромное за совет! я все таки установила локальный веб-сервер (с помощью xampp) и теперь все работает!))

Comment: Ну отлично, если помогло, обычно принимают ответ

Answer (score -1):

Вариант с использованием jQuery (можно и без него - просто писать дольше будет)

Допустим, вы получили XML данные с сервера через AJAX запрос:

```
$.get('/url_of_the_xml_resource')
  .done(function(data){
    data = $.parseXML(data);
    // дальше обрабатываем полученные данные
  })
  .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
console.log('ошибка', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

Ну или просто для примера уже как бы они есть через [jQuery.parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) :

```
var data = $.parseXML(" -- тут ваш Xml как строка --- ")
```

Дальше работаем с переменной 'data'. Например, так:

```
// допустим у нас есть на странице элемент <div id="container"></div> 
// куда мы будем писать наш HTML. 
var container = $('#container'); 

$(data)
  // берем все элементы <string>
  .find('string')
  // и побежали по каждому <string>
  .each(function(index, item){
    // получаем объект XML узла
    var string = $(item)

    // получаем дочерние элементы узла 
    var id = string.find('id').text()
    var name = string.find('name').text()
    var text = string.find('text').text()

    // добавляем результирующий HTML в контейнер
    container
      .append('<h2 id="' + id + '">' + name + '</h2>')
      .append('<p>' + text + '</p>');
  });
```

Писал все без проверок. Должно работать. Попробуйте.

Comment: проблема то в том, что вебсервера нет и никакого запроса на получение файла послать не получиться, если не подкрутить браузер

Comment: не понял, почему кто-то минусует... это спасибо за попытку помочь?

Comment: Это какая-то лабораторная работа что ли? HTML страница не на сервере будет лежать, а просто открываться на локальном диске? 

Некоторые браузеры (включая Chrome) не позволяют грузить файл с локальной файловой системы. Можно обойти, запустив Chrome с ключом --allow-file-access. [Статья](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/file/filesystem/) по теме. 

Но если нужно кросс браузерное решение - следует положить ваши файлы на сервер (можно на локальный, чтобы открываемая веб страница имела URL вроде http://localhost/MyLab/test.html

Comment: Полностью согласен.

Comment: @DmitryPavlov да, лабораторная. html документ будет на локальном диске.. спасибо, попробую)